# Ajax GET error with AngularJS and Spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have an angular function that uses $http request with GET and params :

```
    $scope.getMatchingRecipe = function(){
      $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/recipemanagement/getMatchingRecipeList",
            params: {
                matchingText : $scope.matchingRecipe.text
            }
        }).success(function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
            $scope.recipeList = data;
            console.log($scope.recipeList[0]);
        })
        .error(function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        });  
  };
```

And the MVC controller as :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getMatchingRecipeList")
    public @ResponseBody String getRecipeDropdownList(@RequestParam(value="matchingText") String matchingText){

        List<Recipe> recipeList = recipeServiceImpl.getMatchingRecipes(matchingText);
        for(Recipe recipe : recipeList){
            System.out.println("recipe :"+recipe.getName());
        }
        List<RecipePO> recipePOList = new ArrayList<RecipePO>();
        System.out.println("List Size :"+recipeList.size());
        for(Recipe recipe : recipeList){
            RecipePO recipePO= new RecipePO();
            recipePO.setId(recipe.getId());
            recipePO.setName(recipe.getName());
            recipePO.setDifficulty(recipe.getDifficulty());
            recipePO.setServes(recipe.getServes());
            recipePOList.add(recipePO);
        }

        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(recipePOList);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

However, when the function `getMatchingRecipeList` is called, it returns 404. But when I check the backend console (i.e. the controller function `getRecipeDropdownList` makes a database call through hibernate, so it shows query executed in console), the function is executed.

Comment: Can you check if there is any @ExceptionHandler mapping which is returning 404

Comment: I have configured org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver which will return errorPage.jsp in case of errors.

Comment: no.Usually dont need to.

Comment: are there any error messages being sent to the logs? Or have you tried running in debug mode with breakpoints to see where the error occurs

Comment: as I said it receives an error.jsp as response. On java layer, no error thrown while debuuging.

Comment: try changing `@RequestMapping(value="/getMatchingRecipeList")` by `@RequestMapping(value="/getMatchingRecipeList", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: @JohnKane I double-checked the error messages, and applied try-catch block . It then started showing the errors. Its solved now.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem isnt in the ajax call. The server was throwing an error from backend and hence returned error.jsp page.

The problem : 
Service class was made @Transactional.In DAO layer, I used session.close() (yeah, duh);

The analysis : 
I wrapped up all the functions in try-catch block and got to know of this error. It threw hibernate session already closed error in stacktrace. That's where it was returning error.jsp page

The solution : 
I removed session.close() from DAO class. That solved the issue.